# Why does execution of batch file with FORFILES result in unwanted output of empty lines to console?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I wrote a small batch code which uses command **FORFILES** for looping through directories. OS is Windows 10 Pro x64 and the batch file is executed with `cmd.exe`.

The code is:

```
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo off

SET LogFile=C:\logs
SET Days=1
SET Source=\\SERVER\SHARE\Folder

PUSHD %Source%
FOR /f %%a IN ('type %LogFile%\dirs.log') DO (
    MKDIR "%LogFile%\%%a" 2> NUL
    DEL %LogFile%\%%a\archive.log /Q 2>NUL
    ECHO     Collecting  %%a....
    FORFILES /P %%a /D -%Days% /C "cmd /C ECHO @RELPATH >> %LogFile%\%%a\archive.log" 2> NUL
)
POPD
```

The batch file reads the folders to be scanned from a text file with command **FOR**. This text file is created by following batch code:

`dir.log` creating batch code:

```
PUSHD %Source%
FOR /f %%a IN ('cd') DO SET CurPath=%%a
FOR /f %%a IN ('dir /B /S /AD') DO (
    SET Directory=%%a
    SET Directory=!Directory:%CurPath%\=!
    ECHO !Directory! >> %LogFile%\dirs.log
)

POPD
```

The file `dirs.log` contains folder list with the following folder structure:

```
Folder1
Folder2
Folder1\Subfolder1
Folder1\Subfolder2
Folder2\Subfolder1
```

This text file contains only directory paths line by line with no space or any other character with special meaning for Windows command interpreter. So there is no problem caused by not using `"delims="` in **FOR** loop of first posted batch file.

The command **FORFILES** is executed for each directory path from text file with appropriate parameters.

The batch file outputs the loop variable `a` of **FOR**. But on each batch file execution additional empty lines are randomly output between the lines output with `ECHO     Collecting  %%a....`.

**FORFILES** puts empty lines to console randomly when it is running.

What is causing this?

Comment: Stupidly `forfiles` outputs an empty line before processing the command line behind `/C`. But since you are redirecting the `echo` directly, this cannot be a problem for the log file. Or are you talking about empty lines on the console?

Comment: Yes, in the console. On each run the console output is different look. The files contents are the same. On the console sometimes have empty lines, and empty lines with cursor footprint on the first character. Crazy... When the cursor blink is empty, empty line created. When the blink is on (every second second) sometimes empty line is created with the cursor footprint. Its not functional fail, but looks weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This batch code creates the file `dirs.log` and runs **FORFILES** with redirecting the empty line output by **FORFILES** itself before running `cmd.exe` to device **NUL** to suppress it. A possible error output of **FORFILES** is also suppressed by redirecting it from **STDERR** to **STDOUT** being redirected to device **NUL**. Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for details.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "LogFilesPath=C:\logs"
set "Days=1"
set "Source=\\SERVER\SHARE\Folder"

pushd "%Source%"
if not "%CD:~-1%" == "\" ( set "CurPath=%CD%" ) else set "CurPath=%CD:~0,-1%"
del "%LogFilesPath%\dirs.log" 2>nul

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem WARNING: Directory paths with one or more exclamation marks are
rem          not correct processed by this batch code because of
rem          enabled delayed environment variable expansion.
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /B /S /AD 2^>nul') do (
    set "Directory=%%I"
    set "Directory=!Directory:%CurPath%\=!"
    echo !Directory!>>"%LogFilesPath%\dirs.log"
)
endlocal

if not exist "%LogFilesPath%\dirs.log" goto ExitBatch

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%LogFilesPath%\dirs.log") do (
    mkdir "%LogFilesPath%\%%I" 2>nul
    del "%LogFilesPath%\%%I\archive.log" 2>nul
    echo     Collecting  %%I ...
    %SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "%CurPath%\%%I" /D -%Days% /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C echo @RELPATH>>"%LogFilesPath%\%%I\archive.log"" >nul 2>&1
)

:ExitBatch
popd
endlocal
```

Some notes about this code:

The help of command **SET** output on running `set /?` in a command prompt window lists on last help page the dynamic environment variable `CD` for current directory path. What is not explained is that `%CD%` expands to current directory path with no backslash at end with the exception on current directory is the root directory of a drive. The first **FOR** command line in `dirs.log` creating code can be safely replaced by using `%CD%` with the **IF** condition which is faster than the **FOR** loop running `cmd.exe` in background to execute `cd` and capture its output.

The **DIR** command line is executed by **FOR** in a background command process started with `cmd.exe /C`. **DIR** perhaps finds no directory in which case a confusing error message is output to **STDERR**. That is the reason for using `2>nul` on **DIR** command line. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

There is no space between `echo !Directory!` and `>>"%LogFilesPath%\dirs.log"` because this space would be also written into the log file as trailing space which is not wanted here and would be bad for remaining code.

**FOR** can read a text file itself line by line with skipping empty lines and skipping with default options also lines starting with a semicolon. The option `usebackq` is used to get the log file name enclosed in double quotes interpreted as file name and not as string to process. The option `delims=` defines an empty list of delimiters which disables line splitting done by default on spaces/tabs. Run in a command prompt window `for /?` for help on this command.

Comment: Great explanation. Really solved my problem and cleaned up my code!